# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while calling soap based web service method

Tags: invocationtargetexception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.soap.ClientEncoderDecoder.toMessageInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.soap.client.SOAPXMLDecoder.toMessageInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.client.SOAPMessageDispatcher.receive(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.client.SOAPMessageDispatcher.doSend(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.client.SOAPMessageDispatcher.send(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.soap.internal.DelegateBase.send(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.EndpointIFInvocationHandler.implementSEIMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.EndpointIFInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy17.doCheckForLogin(Unknown Source)
at com.main.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

My web service method

```
@WebMethod
public boolean doCheckForLogin(String userName,String password) throws InvocationTargetException
{   
    System.out.println("login service method");

    final List<String> x=new ArrayList<String>();
    x.add(userName);
    x.add(password);

    UserFacade userfacad=new UserFacade();
    CommunicationObject comObject=new CommunicationObject();
    comObject.setListResult(x);

    return userfacad.doLogin(comObject).isBooleanResult();  
}
```

both user name and password value I am getting here which has sent by client,
but when it reach to Userfacade class initialization, it throws this exception.

Comment: Are you building with Ant or Maven?  What container are you deploying to?  Tomcat, jboss, glassfish, weblogic, etc.?

Comment: i am using Tomcat and running in debug mode eclipse

Comment: Check your libraries included in your eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have multiple copies of the axis libraries loaded.  Check your build (maven? ant?) for duplicate axis jars.  It might also be that the container your're deploying to (jboss, glassfish, weblogic,...) already has a copy of the axis libraries and you need to figure out how to make it only whichever copy is the version you want.